# How to dump iPhone arm64 memory?

Tags: memory, ios

Since GDB is no longer supported on arm64 devices i can't figure any alternative except lldb with debugserver, but unfortunately i can't dump memory with read command always giving me different errors, so my question is there any tool to make a memory dumps for games/apps?